# Rhino Mock, Mock list of interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

How can i Mock list of object in for loop

Here is the code:`

```
 public class SearchResult<T>
    {


        private readonly ISearcher<T> _searcher;
        private readonly IList<ISearchConfigurator> _configurators; 


        public SearchResult(ISearcher<T> searcher, IList<ISearchConfigurator> configurators)
        {
            _searcher = searcher;
            _configurators = configurators;
        }


        public DomainSearchResult<T> FindInAllDomains()
        {
            DomainSearchResult domainSearchResults = new DomainSearchResult<T>();
            foreach (var configurator in _configurators)
            {
                IList<T> results = _searcher.SearchAll(configurator);
                domainSearchResults.Results.Add(_configurator.DomainName, results);
            }
            return domainSearchResults;
        }
    }`
```

the property result is declared in the DomainSearchResult class :

```
IDictionary<string,IList<T>> Results { get; set; }
```

then i tried the following:

```
        [Test]
    public void FindInAllDomains_ReturnsAllRecord()
    {
        //Arrange
        var configuratorMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IList<ISearchConfigurator>>();
        var searchMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISearcher<NativeDs>>();
        var searchRestul = new SearchResult<NativeDs>(searchMock, configuratorMock);

        //Act
        searchRestul.FindInAllDomains(); // calling test fail here

        //Assert
        searchMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SearchAll(null), opt => opt.IgnoreArguments());
    }
```

Error is:
    System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var list = new List<ISearchConfigurator>
          (from x in Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
           select MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISearchConfigurator>()
          );
```